# Is there a memory limit on np.fromfile() method?

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I am trying to read a big file into array with the help of `np.fromfile()`, however, after certain number of bytes it gives MemoryError.

```py
with open(filename,'r') as file:
    data = np.fromfile(file, dtype=np.uint16, count=2048*2048*63)
    data = data.reshape(63, 2048, 2048)
```

It works fine with 2048*2048*63 however not working with 2048*2048*64. How to debug this? I am wondering what is the bottleneck here?

Edit: I am running on Windows 10, RAM 256GB, it is a standalone script, 64bit Python.

Edit2: I followed the advices on comments, now getting the error at 128*2048*2048, works fine with 127*2048*2048.

Comment: How much RAM do you have and what is the bittage of your system?

Comment: How much RAM do you have? How large is your swap/pagefile? Is this standalone code, or part of a larger program with other large allocations? Are you running a 32 or 64 bit version of Python? We need a lot more details to provide useful answers.

Comment: 256GB RAM, but python cannot handle that?

Comment: 64 or 32 bit Python?

Comment: @CanCode: Is the installed Python a 32 or 64 bit version?

Comment: It is a standalone script. 64bit version of python.

Comment: 2048 * 2048 * 2 * 64 = 0.5 GiB. Shouldn't be an issue. Unless you do it a few thousand times

Comment: yeah it shouldn't be, but it gives `MemoryError`.

Comment: I am trying to run only once

Comment: Umm... `np.reshape(63, 2048, 2048)` is not valid; did you mean `data.reshape(63, 2048, 2048)`?

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes, let me fix that

Comment: For the record, on 64 bit CPython 3.7.1 running on Ubuntu bash on Windows, I can't reproduce (and I have *far* less RAM than you, only 12 GB). It loads and reshapes just fine (if I change it to `data.reshape` from `np.reshape`). While it's unlikely to matter, it would be useful to know what OS and specific Python version you're running.

Comment: Is there any way to load file chunk-by-chunk into numpy array? so that maybe i can overcome MemoryError?

Comment: You *shouldn't be getting a memory error*, which should probably worry you. What does `python -c "import sys; print(sys.maxsize)"` give you?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Windows 10 native CPython x64 3.7.1 either. Note: I did change the file open mode from `'r'` to `'rb'` because it should be opened in binary mode, but it worked either way (I'm guessing `numpy` is bypassing the `TextIOWrapper` layer to read the underlying file's raw data directly).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it gives `2147483647`

Comment: @ShadowRanger i switched to 'rb' too. now getting error at 128*2048*2048

Comment: @CanCode: Yeah, on a 64 bit version of Python, `sys.maxsize` would be 9223372036854775807; you're running a 32 bit version, thus your problem.

Comment: @CanCode then you are running a 32bit python process, which has a hard limit of about 4 gigs, although, most OS's put a lower limit than that (*nix about 2, windows even lower if I recall). You need toinstall a 64bit python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Both UNIX and Windows limit to 2 GB of user address space by default IIRC; Windows can be configured to split unevenly so the kernel only gets 1 GB and user space 3 GB, but that's about it. Either way, yeah, 64 bit Python needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite what you believe, you've installed a 32 bit version of Python on your 64 bit operating system, which means virtual address space is limited to only have 2 GB in user mode, and attempts to allocate contiguous blocks of a GB or more can easily fail due to address space fragmentation.

The giveaway is your `sys.maxsize`, which is just the largest value representable by a C `ssize_t` in your build of Python. `2147483647` corresponds to `2**31 - 1`, which is the expected value on 32 bit Python. A 64 bit build would report `9223372036854775807` (`2**63 - 1`).

Uninstall the 32 bit version of Python and [download/install a 64 bit version (link is to 3.7.2 download page)](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-372/) (look for the installer to be labelled as x86-64, *not* x86; the file name would include `amd64`). Annoyingly, [the main page for downloading Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) defaults to offering the 32 bit version for Windows, so you have to scroll down to the links to specific version download pages, click on the latest, then scroll down to the complete list by OS and bittedness and choose appropriately.

Comment: You guys were right, i missed the wrong python interpreter. Fortunately, figured out early. Thank you all.